# Pygame: Why do both buttons activate if one hasn't been checked yet?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, pygame, mouseevent

I've set up a basic Pygame graphical interface, but I'm having trouble with my buttons. I created a `Button` class, and the function to be executed by the button is determined in the `__init__()` method. In other words, I input the function when I create an instance of `Button` via lambda expression. The relevant code of the buttons basically looks like this:

```
class Button():
    def __init__(self, action):
        self.command = action
    def check(self): # To be called while iterating through pygame.event.get()
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP and self.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            self.command()
```

I also created a `Window` class where each instance is list of the buttons to be seen at a time:

```
class Window():
    def __init__(self, buttons):
        self.is_visible = False # This determines whether the buttons in this
                                # window should be updated, checked, and drawn
        self.buttons = list(buttons)
    def open(self):
        self.is_visible = True
    def close(self):
        self.is_visible = False
    def trans(self, new_window):
        self.close()
        new_window.open()
```

Next, I set up two instances of `Window`, each with a `Button` to toggle back to the other:

```
WINDOW_1 = Window([Button(lambda: WINDOW_1.trans(WINDOW_2))])
WINDOW_2 = Window([Button(lambda: WINDOW_2.trans(WINDOW_1))])
```

And finally:

```
WINDOW_1.is_visible = True
```

Here comes the problem.
Each button works exactly how it is supposed to: it closes the open window and opens the closed window. Unfortunately, if I click the mouse in a spot where both buttons overlap (or where they would overlap if they were both visible), the function for `WINDOW_2`'s button is called immediately after the function for `WINDOW_1`'s button is called. Basically, `WINDOW_1` -> `WINDOW_2` -> `WINDOW_1`, and it all happens in the same loop.
However, if we start from `WINDOW_2`, then this happens: `WINDOW_2` -> `WINDOW_1`. It appears that the glitch is only one-way. I just can't figure out what's wrong here, I would really appreciate some help. (Just in case, here's a link to the full code so you can maybe reproduce the problem; I've set the buttons' location so that the bottom half of the first button overlaps the top half of the second: http://pastebin.com/m1zCQLRF). Thank you for reading and thank you in advance for answering!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider these lines (from the pastebin):

```
all_windows=[WINDOW_1,WINDOW_2]
....
for event in pygame.event.get():
    for window in all_windows:
        if window.is_visible:
            for button in window.buttons:
                button.update()
                button.check()
```

If `WINDOW_1`'s button is clicked, `WINDOW_2.is_visible` becomes `True`.

In the next iteration of the `for window in all_windows` loop, the `check` method of `WINDOW_2` will be called because its `is_visible` attribute is now `True`. Because this is still the same iteration of `for event in pygame.event.get()`, `WINDOW_2.check()` sees the same `MOUSEBUTTONUP` event. The Button objects overlap, so the event causes the windows' visibility to toggle a second time, back to the state where `WINDOW_1` is visible, and this is what is drawn.

Incidentally, using `event.pos` would be more accurate than `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` in the `check()` method. The former is the mouse's position at the time the event was posted, while the latter is the current position of the mouse.

### Edit

I got the pastebin running with some tweaking and verified that what I described above is the problem by applying a quick and dirty fix.

First, I edited `Button.check()` so it returns a boolean that shows whether or not its check validated:

```
def check(self):
    if event.type==MOUSEBUTTONUP and self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
        self.command()
        return True

    return False
```

Then altered the code shown above to break out of the `all_windows` loop if `check` returns `True` (i.e. if a window is closed).

```
for window in all_windows:
    if window.is_visible:
        for button in window.buttons:
            button.update()
            _break = button.check()
        if _break:
            break
```

Now the windows close and open as expected when a button is clicked. Again, that's not a "real" fix just a confirmation of what caused the problem.